# Conflict between RequireJs and NodeJS definitions in Typescript

Tags: node.js, requirejs, typescript

I got the Typescript RequireJS definition from Definitely Typed - which has an ambient declaration of Require that conflicts with the NodeJs command "require". Here's the declaration and the error:

Declaration:

```
declare var require: Require;
```

Error:

```
C:/.../require.d.ts(320,13): error TS2134: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'require' must be of type '{ resolve(id: string): string; cache: any; extensions: any; main: any; (id: string): any; }', but here has type 'Require'.
```

Comment: Just to be clear - you're using RequireJS in Node?

Comment: RequireJs is on the client side and NodeJS is on the server side. But there is a common typescript header file to which all definition files refer. I've done this because there are a huge number of dependencies between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is true. What I had to do was simply use declare var require:any and not reference nodejs or RequireJS.

Would appreciate if you can open a bug here : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

Reason why it's tricky is because you don't actually have both node and RequireJS in the same environment. It's a compile time reuse thing we need to support.

Comment: Thanks. Here's another question, you might be able to help me with. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21382200/trouble-with-backbone-and-typescript

Comment: And, unfortunately, I don't have a github account yet - so I can't file the ticket.

Comment: @basarat No. They don't run a browser. Some of them don't need a browser environment at all to run. Some of them run with jsdom, which is not a browser but simulates a DOM environment.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue while trying to integrate [monaco-editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/index.html) in my application. Workaround is pretty simple.

1. Insert this line 
   `<script>window.requirejs = window.require;</script>`
   after included `require.js` or `loader.js` in your html.
2. Then in your .ts file where you want to use requirejs, replace all `require` with `requirejs`. This alias is already defined in [`require.d.ts`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/requirejs)
3. Done!

Comment: This will resolve only issue about require key word. Not original issue.

Comment: I was abel to resolve this by commenting line in index.d.ts of requirejs. Keeping comments here in case anyone stumbles here on this comment :)

Answer (score -1):

i was having this issue and removed this from the typings.json

```
"require": "registry:dt/require#2.1.20+20160316155526"
```

not sure how it got into my project, but i'm not using require client side.