# Trouble with Backbone and Typescript

Tags: backbone.js, typescript, webstorm

I am learning backbone over Typescript and I got the header file for backbone. I am trying to create a view in which I've referenced "this" inside the render function. But Webstorm is throwing an error on that:

```
class QuestionView extends Backbone.View{
    model = new Question();
    template: (data:any) => string;

    constructor(options){
        super(options);
        this.tagName = "div";
        this.template = _.template($("#add-question").html());
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
    }

    render(){
        this.$el.html()(this.template(this.model.toJSON())); // The error is pointing to   the first "this" literal in this line
        return this;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
C:/.../Main.ts(40,9): error TS2088: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.
```

Comment: Its defined in the .d.ts

Comment: Assuming ``$el`` is a jQuery object, and ``jQuery.fn.html`` has not been overridden, then ``$el.html()`` would return a string. So ``this.$el.html()(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));`` is trying invoke a string as a function. Perhaps the first pair of parentheses is a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually with `this` problems it is related to scope, but in your case it is just related to a typo in your `html` method call:

```
render(){
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON())); // fixed
    return this;
}
```

To set the HTML of an element, you pass the HTML inside the parenthesis of the `html` method - you accidentally passed no arguments (so this GETS the HTML, rather than SETS the HTML) and then tried to call the resulting string of HTML like a function.

```
this.$el.html() // returns a string of HTML
this.$el.html('<div>Hello World</div>') // sets the html to the supplied string
```